# 403 Unauthorized error to derivative service Autodesk Forge (Viewer not showing)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I am currently working on a project using the Autodesk Forge platform. I have been using the Viewer, Model Derivative, and Data Management APIs without any issues since yesterday that suddenly when I tried to open a model (uploaded weeks ago) and returned a 403 error on requests to view the model.

I did some research with Postman and I tried to do the same calls I'm doing in my app with the same credentials. The OAuth API and Data Management API seem to work correctly because they let me have access to the token and upload a model. The problem seems to be when I try to translate the uploaded model.

The call I'm using in Postman is:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job

And what Postman is returning is:
403 Unauthorized.

```
{
    "developerMessage": "The client_id specified does not have access to the api product",
"moreInfo":"https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/",
"errorCode": "AUTH-001"
}
```

Something similar happens when I try to open a model in my app.
The Request URL is the next one: [https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/{urn}?domain=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/%7Burn%7D?domain=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080)

And the returned code is 403 Unauthorized.
These are the headers in the call:
[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l36UO.png)

The codebase hasn't changed in weeks and exhibits the same behavior leading me to believe it's a code change in the referenced Autodesk Forge libraries or a service issue on the derivative or viewer service.

I can upload cut-up code if required.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you try to call the same API with other tools like Postman to see if it works?

Comment: Besides, please check the API selections of the client id in your https://forge.autodesk.com/myapps and also check your subscription state.

Comment: Hello, the issue was the subscription. We needed to renew it. Thank you!

Comment: Nice, thank you for your good news!